# Figure caption replace default ":" with a space

Tags: captions

How can I replace the usual ":" with a space in the Figure captions.

```
> Figure 3: Blah blah.....................
```

with

```
> Figure 3 Blah blah.....................
```

Comment: Use the `caption` package with `\captionsetup[figure]{font={normalfont},format=plain,labelsep=quad}` for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a MWE using the `caption` package and `\captionsetup`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font={normalfont},format=plain,labelsep=space}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\[  X_i=
    \begin{cases}
    0                           & \text{ for } i=0\\
    (X_{i-1}\oplus A_i)\cdot H  & \text{ for } i=1,\dotsc,m-1
    \end{cases}
\]
\caption{Math Thingy}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You may also want to try `quad` instead of `space`. I may even add that there are advanced enhancements like the `\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator` which enables you to declare your own space separator or symbols as you wish. See below for some samples:

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{enspace}{\enspace}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{oneem}{\hskip1em}
```

And used as:

```
\captionsetup[figure]{font={normalfont},format=plain,labelsep=enspace}
\captionsetup[figure]{font={normalfont},format=plain,labelsep=oneem}
```

Just for fun and to illustrate other symbolic implementation:

[image]

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{triangle}{%
\,\raisebox{0.375ex}{$\scriptstyle\blacktriangleright$}~}
```

and is used as above